# Styling edges in Cytoscape.js for a Family Tree

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js, family-tree

I have a Family Tree application that uses Django and I am trying to use http://js.cytoscape.org for the UI.

I would like to style edges between **romantic partners** like this:

http://www.eprintablecalendars.com/images/arts-and-crafts/family-tree.jpg

which is what you commonly see (the square-U).

I am completely new to Cytoscape.js, and haven't been able to find any answers in the docs or other threads.

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing is not edges but [hyperedges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergraph).  A hyperedge has multiple sources and/or targets.  You can simulate hyperedge with intermediary nodes or in your case `curve-style: segments` in 2.5+.